# Windows xcopy is not working in python

Tags: python, xcopy

When I am doing

```
xcopy "D:\Accessories\My File\read-me.rtf" "D:\Any Folder\Destn"
```

It is copying fine

Same thing I am doing in python (2.7)

```
import os
source = "D:\Accessories\My File\read-me.rtf"
target = "D:\Any Folder\Destn"
output = os.system ("xcopy %s %s" % (source, target))
```

But this code is throwing error that `Invalid number of parameters`

Is it a right way to invoke ? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are spaces in your "source" and "target" pathnames.  Try quoting it in the os.system call ie

```
output = os.system ("""xcopy "%s" "%s" """ % (source, target))
```

Comment: Let me chk, I was trying  with  \"%s\"

Comment: In another case I am getting Parse Error. Any idea ?