# Python copy larger file too slow

Tags: python, performance, copy

I am trying to copy a large file (> 1 GB) from hard disk to usb drive using `shutil.copy`. A simple script depicting what I am trying to do is:-

```
import shutil
src_file = "source\to\large\file"
dest = "destination\directory"
shutil.copy(src_file, dest)
```

It takes only 2-3 min on linux. But the same file copy on same file takes more that 10-15 min under Windows. Can somebody explain why and give some solution, preferably using python code?

**Update 1**

Saved the file as test.pySource file size is 1 GB. Destinantion directory is in USB drive. Calculated file copy time with ptime. Result is here:-

```
ptime.exe test.py

ptime 1.0 for Win32, Freeware - http://www.
Copyright(C) 2002, Jem Berkes <jberkes@pc-t

===  test.py ===

Execution time: 542.479 s
```

542.479 s == 9 min. I don't think `shutil.copy` should take 9 min for copying 1 GB file.

**Update 2**

Health of the USB is good as same script works well under Linux. Calculated time with same file under windows native xcopy.Here is the result.

```
ptime 1.0 for Win32, Freeware - http://www.pc-tools.net/
Copyright(C) 2002, Jem Berkes <jberkes@pc-tools.net>

===  xcopy F:\test.iso L:\usb\test.iso
1 File(s) copied

Execution time: 128.144 s
```

128.144 s == 2.13 min. I have 1.7 GB free space even after copying test file.

Comment: With than many informations, I'm afraid that the answer to your question is "no" !

Comment: The question is very simple and the script also very simple just to copy a file from source to destination. Added few lines to look like a python script. I dont understand why down voted :-(

Comment: I suspect that part of the issue here is that Windows has recognised the USB disk as a portable device and has optimised it for fast removal (at the expense of caching). See for example https://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-disable-disk-write-caching-windows-7-8

Comment: Python 3.8 includes a major overhaul / speed up of shutil. See answer below for links

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just to add some interesting information: WIndows does not like the tiny buffer used on the internals of the shutil implementation.

I've quick tried the following:

- Copied the original **shutil.py** file to the example script folder and renamed it to **myshutil.py**
- Changed the 1st line to `import myshutil`
- Edited the **myshutil.py** file and changed the **copyfileobj** from

> def copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length=16*1024):

to

> def copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length=16*1024*1024):

Using a 16 MB buffer instead of 16 KB caused a huge performance improvement.

Maybe Python needs some *tuning* targeting Windows internal filesystem characteristics?

**Edit:**

Came to a better solution here. At the start of your file, add the following:

```
import shutil

def _copyfileobj_patched(fsrc, fdst, length=16*1024*1024):
    """Patches shutil method to hugely improve copy speed"""
    while 1:
        buf = fsrc.read(length)
        if not buf:
            break
        fdst.write(buf)
shutil.copyfileobj = _copyfileobj_patched
```

This is a simple patch to the current implementation and worked flawlessly here.

**Python 3.8+:**
Python 3.8 includes a major overhaul of shutil, including increasing the windows buffer from 16KB to 1MB (still less than the 16MB suggested in this ticket). See [ticket](https://bugs.python.org/issue33671) , [diff](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/4a172ccc739065bb658c75e8929774a8e94af9e9#diff-69f781dfa4a6697ad701fd742bc0d81e)

Comment: Found this on the web: http://blogs.blumetech.com/blumetechs-tech-blog/2011/05/faster-python-file-copy.html

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/shutil.py they seem to have changed the `copyfileobj` to use a `length` value depending on the OS. It now uses 1MB buffer (instead of 16K) when running on *Windows*.

Comment: Thank you for this. This is very interesting!

Comment: Will this also work for the function shutil.copyfile instead of shutil.copy? I am sorry, I am a capable but novice python programmer and I don't understand on a deep level how your answer interacts with the shutil copy function. I want to use copyfile so I can rename the file when I put it in the new location

Comment: As python is dynamic, the idea behind the solution was to replace the original function by a patched version, defining a new default buffer size. Open the library sources (Lib/shutil.py). There you will see that the _copyfileobj_patched is almost a clone from the original one, except for the 'default' parameter.
Edit: You should also note that shutil.copyfile consumes shutil.copyfileobj...

Comment: @Chau it looks like the change to 1MB buffer is new in python 3.8: https://bugs.python.org/issue33671

Comment: Can we have a custom buffer length in shutil?

Answer (score 6):

Your problem has nothing to do with Python. In fact, the Windows copy process is really poor compared to the Linux system.

You can improve this by using `xcopy` or `robocopy` according to this post: [Is (Ubuntu) Linux file copying algorithm better than Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/302753/is-ubuntu-linux-file-copying-algorithm-better-than-windows-7). But in this case, you have to make different calls for Linux and Windows...

```
import os
import shutil
import sys

source = "source\to\large\file"
target = "destination\directory"

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    os.system('xcopy "%s" "%s"' % (source, target))
else:
    shutil.copy(source, target)
```

See also:

- [Actual Performance, Perceived Performance](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/actual-performance-perceived-performance.html), Jeff Atwood blog post about this subject
- [Windows xcopy is not working in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975481/windows-xcopy-is-not-working-in-python), which gives the syntax for using xcopy on Windows in fact

Comment: I have to settle down by calling system command subprocess.call(["xcopy",source ,target], shell=True). But there is an issue with `shutil.copy()` for sure.

Comment: This answer will work, however, the answer below provides an explanation for the issue, does not require system specific code, and is pythonic.